# AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'requestedDate'

Tags: python, django

I just want to filter the CustomerPurchaseOrder(inputdate) to CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail(requestedDate). How do i do that?

This is my current views.py

```
record = CustomerPurchaseOrder.objects.filter(profile__in=client.values_list('id'))
date = CustomerPurchaseOrder.objects.filter(profile__in=client.values_list('id'))
status = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter(profile__in=client.values_list('id')) \
    .filter(customer_Purchase_Order__in=record.values_list('id')).filter(inputdate=date.requestedDate)
```

this is my models

```
class CustomerPurchaseOrder(models.Model):

    profile = models.ForeignKey(Customer,
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                verbose_name="Client Account")
    customerdeliveryaddress = models.ForeignKey(CustomerDeliveryAddress, 
                                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                                verbose_name="Delivery Address")

    process = models.ForeignKey('Process', 
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                verbose_name="Process")
    requestedDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


class CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Customer,
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                verbose_name="Client Account")

    products = models.ForeignKey(Product, 
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                 verbose_name="Product")
    customer_Purchase_Order = models.ForeignKey(CustomerPurchaseOrder,
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                 verbose_name="CustomerPurchaseOrder")
    inputdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is my full traceback

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\LastProject\OnlinePalengke\customAdmin\decorators.py" in wrapper_func
  42.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\LastProject\OnlinePalengke\customAdmin\views.py" in client
  116.         .filter(customer_Purchase_Order__in=record.values_list('id')).filter(inputdate=records.requestedDate)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /client/
```

Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'requestedDate'

UPDATE

when i tried this

```
status = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter(profile__in=client.values_list('id')) \
        .filter(customer_Purchase_Order__in=record.values_list('id')).filter(inputdate=date.values('requestedDate'))
```

I receive this error

```
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
```

Comment: *`filter(inputdate=records.requestedDate)`* Here the `records` is a ***`QuerySet`***, not a  ***`CustomerPurchaseOrder` instance***

Comment: mr @ArakkalAbu I dont get it.

Comment: what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this with [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expression which allows you to access model fields from the very same object:

```
status = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter(profile__in=client.values_list('id')) \
        .filter(customer_Purchase_Order__in=record.values_list('id')).filter(inputdate=F('customer_Purchase_Order__requestedDate'))
```